# How do I disable vim/gvim warnings about missing CR (W15)

Tags: vim

I routinely move files back and forth between Unix (Linux) and Windows 10 Home, and the files are always using the Unix  line endings (fileformat=unix is set in my ~/.vimrc file on Windows).  When I open those files on Windows, despite setting fileformat, I get warnings about a missing  (W15).

A simple ESC or RETURN/ENTER (whichever you prefer to call it) clears those, but they are getting really annoying.  So my question, which I hope has a simple answer is, how do I disable those W15 warnings so I just don't see them anymore?

I've read :help W15, and it seems to imply that having fileformat set should make it work (which I'm guessing means it shouldn't be whining), but that's not what I'm seeing...it's still whining every time.

Thanks,
--jim

Comment: The option you need to set is `:help 'fileformats'`, with an "s", not `:help 'fileformat'`.

Comment: so "set fileformats=unix
Ok, I can do that.  Thanks.

Result (of doing a :source ~/.vimrc)

Error detected while processing C:/jim/.vimrc:
line   1:
W15:  Warning:  wrong line separator, ^M may be missing

No change.

Comment: I also tried :set fileformats="unix,dos" ... same result again....sourcing any file (e.g., ~/.vimrc) results in the same W15 error.

Comment: @GTbrewer note that there shouldn't be any quotes there: `set fileformats=unix,dos`

Comment: Oh, ok.  :help shows quotes:   Vim+Vi MS-Windows: "dos,unix",
That's why I used quotes.

Comment: That worked, at least for opening, but not sourcing (e.g., if some setting seems hosed, etc., :source ~/.vimrc ... that still shows that stupid error that seems to think I need <CR> at line ends for some stupid reason.  I have the following set in my .vimrc:

set fileformats=unix,dos
set fileformat=unix

Seems to me it should never gripe about a missing ^M.  Unix files don't end with a ^M, and I'm only using the Unix file format. Still annoyed.  I'm using M$ on this gaming laptop for Lenovo apps and apps for my graphics card. I'm starting to think of losing those and going back to Linux.